# DropShadow effect for Winform is slow?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I am applying Drop Shadow effect to my borderless win Form by overriding the `CreateParams` property and it works fine also but I don't know why it slow down the application while I am moving the Form.

My Code:

```
 private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x20000;
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
              CreateParams parameters = base.CreateParams;
              if (OSFeature.IsPresent(SystemParameter.DropShadow))
              {
                  parameters.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
              }
              return parameters;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CS_DROPSHADOW creates a region of transparency.  It takes a lot more time to blend the drop shadow with whatever might be underneath and then render it.  This is especially true on Windows 2000/XP.  I think they improved performance for transparency in Windows Vista/7.

This style was originally intended for things like menus, which can't be moved by the user.  The performance of CS_DROPSHADOW was therefore probably not a major concern, either.

Comment: then can you please help me to apply shadow effect to my winform in any other way if possible?